# Flask on Apache: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, apache, flask

I deployed the my Flask app on apache on a remote server, however I get a FileNotFoundError when the load_transcript() function is called. However, I do not get this error when the download_sound_file() function is called. Both functions work perfectly on my local deployment. I have provided my directory structure below. Could someone please provide some suggestions about how to debug this?

Here is the relevant code in app.py:

```
def readFile(filename):
    fileSegments = []
    with open(filename, 'r') as csvfile:
        spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter='\t', quotechar='|')
        for row in spamreader:
            outputDict = {}
            outputDict["id"] = row[0]
            outputDict["speakerID"] = row[1]
            outputDict["text"] = row[2]
            fileSegments.append(outputDict)
    return fileSegments

@app.route('/transcript/<meetingid>')
def load_transcript(meetingid):
    template_variables = {}
    template_variables["segments"] = readFile("transcripts/"+meetingid+".txt")
    return render_template('annotator.html', data=template_variables)

@app.route('/music/<meetingid>')
def download_sound_file(meetingid):
    return send_file('audio/'+meetingid+'/'+meetingid+".wav")
```

Here is my directory structure:

```
.
├── app.py
├── app.wsgi
├── _templates
|   ├── annotator.html
|   └── ...
├── transcripts
|   ├── Bdb001.txt
|   └── ...
├── audio
|   ├── Bdb001
|   |   ├── Bdb001.wav
|   |   ├── Bdb001.mp3
|   |   └── ...
|   └── ...
```

app.wsgi:

```
activate_this = '/home/ubuntu/meeting_data_parser/annotator/env2/bin/activate_this.py'
with open(activate_this) as f:
    exec(f.read(), dict(__file__=activate_this))

import sys
import logging

logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr)
sys.path.insert(0,"/var/www/html/annotator")

from app import app as application
```

Apache config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    WSGIDaemonProcess annotator threads=5
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/annotator/app.wsgi

    <Directory flaskproject>
        WSGIProcessGroup annotator
        WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Directory>    


    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

Here is the stack trace of the error:

```
[Tue Jun 12 12:47:48.437405 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 32518:tid 140647948343040] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Tue Jun 12 12:47:48.437409 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 32518:tid 140647948343040]   File "/home/ubuntu/meeting_data_parser/annotator/env2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2292, in wsgi_app
[Tue Jun 12 12:47:48.437412 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 32518:tid 140647948343040]     response = self.full_dispatch_request()
[Tue Jun 12 12:47:48.437415 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 32518:tid 140647948343040]   File "/home/ubuntu/meeting_data_parser/annotator/env2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1815, in full_dispatch_request
[Tue Jun 12 12:47:48.437418 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 32518:tid 140647948343040]     rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
[Tue Jun 12 12:47:48.437421 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 32518:tid 140647948343040]   File "/home/ubuntu/meeting_data_parser/annotator/env2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1718, in handle_user_exception
[Tue Jun 12 12:47:48.437424 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 32518:tid 140647948343040]     reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
[Tue Jun 12 12:47:48.437426 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 32518:tid 140647948343040]   File "/home/ubuntu/meeting_data_parser/annotator/env2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
[Tue Jun 12 12:47:48.437429 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 32518:tid 140647948343040]     raise value
[Tue Jun 12 12:47:48.437431 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 32518:tid 140647948343040]   File "/home/ubuntu/meeting_data_parser/annotator/env2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1813, in full_dispatch_request
[Tue Jun 12 12:47:48.437434 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 32518:tid 140647948343040]     rv = self.dispatch_request()
[Tue Jun 12 12:47:48.437436 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 32518:tid 140647948343040]   File "/home/ubuntu/meeting_data_parser/annotator/env2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request
[Tue Jun 12 12:47:48.437439 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 32518:tid 140647948343040]     return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
[Tue Jun 12 12:47:48.437441 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 32518:tid 140647948343040]   File "/var/www/html/annotator/app.py", line 46, in load_annotation
[Tue Jun 12 12:47:48.437446 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 32518:tid 140647948343040]     template_variables["segments"] = readFile("transcripts/"+meetingid+".txt")
[Tue Jun 12 12:47:48.437460 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 32518:tid 140647948343040]   File "/var/www/html/annotator/app.py", line 11, in readFile
[Tue Jun 12 12:47:48.437463 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 32518:tid 140647948343040]     with open(filename, 'r') as csvfile:
[Tue Jun 12 12:47:48.437467 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 32518:tid 140647948343040] FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'transcripts/Bdb001.txt'
```

Comment: The directory structure doesn't show if the file 'transcripts/Bdb001.txt' actually exists. The `load_transcript` and `download_sound_file` functions are trying to read different files so the fact that 1 works and the other doesn't isn't too surprising based on the information you provided.

Comment: Ah sorry I just updated that - I made sure the files all exist. Including Bdb001.txt

Comment: Can you show the Flask or Apache configuration for your static assets?

Comment: By running code from `annotator/app.py` without a relative path, it's probably trying to open `annotator/transcripts/Bdb001.txt`

Comment: Added my Apache config. I didn't define any static assets folder for Flask as it worked perfectly locally.

Comment: You could try outputting the current working directory using `os.getcwd()` and double check it is set to the path you are expecting during the `load_transcript()` function.

Comment: Ok update: I managed to make it work :D

I specified the absolute path to the directory: `readFile("home/ubuntu/meeting_data_parser/annotator/transcripts/"+meetingid+".txt")` and it was able to find the file.

I still don't understand why this was not a problem in the `download_sound_file` function, so if anyone can help answer that it will be good to know for the futue!

thank you @c3st7n - using `os.getcwd()` I discovered this issue!

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that something is causing your working directory to change: can you output the current working directory using `os.getcwd()` in both functions and see if they are the same?